# Org mode table, show different background on current row, or, alternate even/odd org rows

Tags: org-mode, org-table

On wider tables in org mode, it is hard to see the current line.

In emacs org mode table, is there a way to display different background for the current row, or alternate background for even/odd rows?

(I am not concerned with export, although if the even/odd alternate background would export that would be great as well)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of, but (when editing) you can use M-x hl-line-mode to clearly see the current row highlighted.

Comment: I was hoping for a more specific approach but this is a good suggestion in lack of an org solution.

Comment: I'd like it too ;-)  OTOH, for HTML export, you can easily apply CSS rules to get that effect too. GitHub style does it (for example, see https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven).

Answer (score 3):

The package [`stripe-buffer`](https://github.com/sabof/stripe-buffer) provides `stripe-table-mode` which provides odd/even row highlighting for org tables. (It also gives you `stripe-listify-buffer` which provides similar row highlighting for any list-style buffer like dired, ibuffer, etc.)